Trying to add an application on Argocd but fails with lookup argocd-repo-server: i/o timeout
I am trying to add an application on Argocd by adding the git repo,however fails with the below exception.
ComparisonError
Failed to load target state: failed to generate manifest for source 1 of 1: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup argocd-repo-server: i/o timeout"

i have restarted the argocd deployments and also tried to clone the git repo manual on argocd pods with succees.Note the k8s dns pods running without any issue.


Where is your repo server hosted? Are you sure you have a dns record for the host as queried bei argocd?

Finnaly i have change the redis image version to
redis:
image:
tag: '6.2.4'
and i have restarted argocd-application-controller-0.
Afterwards the issue has been fixed.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
